# Connection IO not logging in console

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I've went through at least 10-15 different stackoverflow questions, I've tried everything I could think of, but I cannot get it to console.log('a user connected') when someone goes to localhost:3000.

I have the main.js, index.html, and css inside a /public folder.
The app.js is inside the root folder.
Also, I have the following dependencies installed:
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
And I have checked the network file for main.js in inspect element, there's no 404 error or any red/ error marks.

Server Side - app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Routing
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('a user disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', PORT);
});
```

Client Side - main.js

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.min.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Left Channel Panel -->
      <div class="channel"><h4 class="channel-col">Channel</h4></div>

      <!-- Center Chat Panel -->
      <div class="chat">
        <h4 class="channel-name">#general-lounge</h4>

        <div class="socket-chat">agag</div>

        <div class="message-box">
          <div class="message">
            <i class="submit fas fa-paper-plane fa-lg"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Right Online Panel -->
      <div class="online"><h4 class="online-col">Online</h4></div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02926adb38.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Client Side -->
    <script src="./main.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per https://socket.io/docs/, `io.connect();` has url as parameter. Did you tried `var socket = io() `? - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-socket-in-nodejs/.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, did not work either unfortunately.

Comment: Have you started the server i:e `node app.js`?

Comment: Yes, it shows Server listening at port 3000.

Comment: `var socket = io.connect();`. what is output of `console.log(socket)`?

Comment: Nothing in console their either. Also, I checked the network file inside chrome inspect element, and the main.js has no 404 errors either. https://i.imgur.com/extmR47.png

Comment: Yup it's getting loaded in the network. https://i.imgur.com/4I4iTx9.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205050/discussion-between-don-and-random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "io" in your main.js is undefined. I was able to get this working by including the socket.io-client in the html. Include the following above the main.js script tag in your html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

You may also need to include a URL in your socket connection. See below:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost');
```

Also run the following to install socket.io-client if necessary:

```
npm install --save socket.io-client
```